# Is it possible for total experimental pressure to be higher than theoretical in a converging section of a venturi tube with water as its medium?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I recently did an experiment on Bernoulli's theorem and when looking at the results for the measured total theoretical and experimental head, I found that the experimental head was above the theoretical at the end of the converging section. I did some research about this issue and found something called shear-induced bubble formation, and I am not sure if this is the reason for the higher total experimental head over the theoretical measurement, or is there another reason. The results are as shown, where the graph y-axis is the head measurements and the x-axis is the distance from the datum.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

It's far more likely that the reading at $A$ is too low and not measuring the true total, rather than that the total has genuinely increased by $B$ or $C$. If the probe isn't quite aligned with the flow direction, or if it's in a boundary layer or the wake of something upstream, the reading will be slightly too low.

So maybe take the peak value of $249.24$ as your total theoretical head, or even round to $250$.

Also it's only off by around 1%, so could just be uncertainty or miscalibration in the instruments you're measuring with.